# Hide certain navbar link items on service unavailable

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have a project that has a "service unavailable" component built in. Whenever this component is shown on a page, it is to hide certain navbar link items and only show a select few.

The navbar is also a separate component and each nav link item has it's own id.

Should I be using some like setState?

I'm new to react and any help is appreciated. If you need some code for me to add, also let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think global state is something you are looking for. Using redux you could easily set `serviceUnavailable` state and check it in navbar, and then render your links accordingly. You can learn more about approach, usage and installation here:

https://react-redux.js.org/

Comment: Keep in mind, there are more libraries that handle global state. Redux came to my mind because it is one of the most popular ones, and I personally use it a lot.